# OpenVZ Swap space?

Tags: memory, openvz, swap

From what I understand with OpenVZ you just increase privvmpages and vmguarpages for the swap memory, and even though the guest shows it as RAM the host will swap it were possible.

Am I right here or does it work differently

Update: Even setting the RAM to 3gb (swap+memory) for the container it still messes up because some programs allocate a lot of memory they don't use. I'm switching back to a full virtualization solution but a good answer to this would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds right to me... but I forwarded this question to someone who is more knowledgeable. Maybe that person will provide some more details.